# How do you put an ASP.Net MVC 4 application in source control?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, version-control, nuget

So, I created a brand new ASP.Net MVC 4 application from Visual Studio. Much to my surprise, an "empty" project weighed in at 54Mb after pulling in and compiling all the packages. Obviously, I don't want to stick unnecessary things in source control, especially binaries.

I figured that the `packages.config` file would control packages so that it would redownload them when missing and I could delete the `packages` directory, but that didn't work. After deleting `packages`, I get errors like : "`BundleCollection` could not be found". I checked in the references of the project and there seems to be no problems resolving any of them. Where does this come from? I'm also missing apparently common namespaces like `System.Web.Optimization`. I have a reference to it in my project and Visual Studio reports the reference is "resolved", but it points to the (deleted) package directory, which I assume is why it's erroring out.

What is the idiomatic method of putting an ASP.Net MVC 4 application in source control, especially with management of NuGet packages?

Answer (score 4):

This is a great article on using NuGet without adding the packages to source control.  The article is for VS 2010, but I am doing the same thing in VS 2012

[Using NuGet without adding packages to source control](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages)

Comment: Excellent link, thanks! One question. It creates a `.nuget` folder, which I assume needs to be placed under source control, but that folder contains a `NuGet.exe` file. Do I need to put that under source control?

Comment: Yes, put everything under the .nuget folder int source control.  Shoudl be the NuGet.config, NuGet.exe and NuGet.targets